# Computation of volume of a set determined by inequalities

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, regions

I am beginning Mathematica user. Please help me to solve the following problem with Mathematica - I need to compute value of 
$$Е=\{2x^7 \le y \le 7 x^7;4y^2 \le z \le 5 y^2;3z^9 \le x \le 8 z^9\}$$

How to do it with Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an implicit region and then use `Volume[]` to compute the volume. Depending on the definition of the region, the computation time may vary.

```
R1 = ImplicitRegion[
  2 x^7 <= y <= 7 x^7 && 4 y^2 <= z <= 5 y^2 && 
   3 z^9 <= x <= 8 z^9, {{x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}}]
R1//Volume//N
(*0.000556097*)
```

You can also discretize the region to compute the volume, but the downside is, you may have to manually adjust the option `MaxCellMeasure` to get a good enough result.

```
DiscretizeRegion[R1, 
  MaxCellMeasure -> {"Volume" -> .0000001}] // Volume
(*0.0005533*)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a result with infinite precision (and if you have an older version of MMA), wrap the conditions in "Boole" and Integrate

```
(int1 = 
   Integrate[
      Boole[2 x^7 <= y <= 7 x^7 && 4 y^2 <= z <= 5 y^2 && 
        3 z^9 <= x <= 
        8 z^9], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 
                 Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}]) // Timing

(*    {88.703, -(1/2832984) 3125 (105 2^(17/125) - 35 2^(83/125) 3^(103/125) - 
   42 2^(38/125) 5^(52/125) + 
   14 2^(104/125) 3^(103/125) 5^(52/125) - 
   15 2^(38/125) 7^(104/125) + 
   6 2^(59/125) 5^(52/125) 7^(104/125) - 
   4 3^(103/125) 5^(52/125) 7^(104/125) + 
   5 3^(103/125) 14^(104/125))}    *)


 N[int1, 20]

(*    0.00055609650303342367641    *)
```